# Boost.spirit segmentation fault when parsing with composite grammar

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit

Trying to write parser for .fnt files:

```
int main()
{
    const auto word = qi::lexeme [ + qi::alnum ];
    const auto literal = qi::lexeme[ '"' >> + ( qi::char_ - '"' ) >> '"' ];
    const auto value = literal | qi::double_;
    const auto pair = word >> '=' >> value;
    const auto line = word >> ( + pair ) >> qi::eol;
    const auto document = + line;

    std::ifstream in( "input.fnt" );
    in.unsetf( std::ios::skipws );
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator begin(in);
    boost::spirit::istream_iterator end;

    qi::parse( begin, end, document );
}
```

Execution fails with **Segmentation fault** error within deeps of boost::spirit. But when I change grammar to not be composed of intermediate grammars (rules?) - it succeeds.

At [Internal Boost::Spirit code segfaults when parsing a composite grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678246/internal-boostspirit-code-segfaults-when-parsing-a-composite-grammar) was said **expression templates keep internal references to temporaries** but all the grammars do exist during the **qi::parse()** call.
What could be the problem? How can I break composite grammars into more meaningful pieces?

P.S. When changing **const auto** to **#define** and remove **=** sign - it succeeds :) (**qi::parse()** returns **false**, but at least returns).

Comment: I previously linked this as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables/22027181#22027181 because it is. Below are some hints to make the parser actually succeed on a simple FNT file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving you some free advice beyond the duplicate: [Assigning parsers to auto variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22023779/assigning-parsers-to-auto-variables/22027181#22027181)

Let's parse the simple FNT sample:

```
info face="Arial" size=32 bold=0 italic=0 charset="" unicode=1 stretchH=100 smooth=1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0,0 spacing=1,1 outline=0
common lineHeight=32 base=26 scaleW=256 scaleH=256 pages=0 packed=0 alphaChnl=1 redChnl=0 greenChnl=0 blueChnl=0
chars count=0
```

Notes:

1. use a skipper to allow for the insignificant whitespace. In this case, use `qi::blank` because it keeps `eol` significant
2. allow for multivalue (`"property=0,0,0"` style) by doing `double % ','`
3. use BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG with rules
4. declare skipperless rules for implicit lexemes ([Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a39c14df1e830ec3)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <fstream>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    qi::rule<It> 
        word    = +qi::alnum,
        literal = '"' >> *(qi::char_ - '"') >> '"';
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> 
        value   = qi::raw[literal | qi::double_ % ','];

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((word)(literal)(value))

    const auto pair     = qi::copy(word >> '=' >> value);
    const auto line     = qi::copy(word >> ( + pair ) >> qi::eol);
    const auto document = qi::copy(+ line);

    std::ifstream in("input.fnt");
    in.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    It begin(in), end;

    bool ok = qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, document, qi::blank);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ok << '\n';
}
```

Prints:

```
true
```

With debug info:

```xml
<word>
  <try>info face="Arial" si</try>
  <success> face="Arial" size=3</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<word>
  <try>face="Arial" size=32</try>
  <success>="Arial" size=32 bol</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>"Arial" size=32 bold</try>
  <literal>
    <try>"Arial" size=32 bold</try>
    <success> size=32 bold=0 ital</success>
    <attributes>[]</attributes>
  </literal>
  <success> size=32 bold=0 ital</success>
  <attributes>[[", A, r, i, a, l, "]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>size=32 bold=0 itali</try>
  <success>=32 bold=0 italic=0 </success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>32 bold=0 italic=0 c</try>
  <literal>
    <try>32 bold=0 italic=0 c</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> bold=0 italic=0 cha</success>
  <attributes>[[3, 2]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>bold=0 italic=0 char</try>
  <success>=0 italic=0 charset=</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>0 italic=0 charset="</try>
  <literal>
    <try>0 italic=0 charset="</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> italic=0 charset=""</success>
  <attributes>[[0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>italic=0 charset="" </try>
  <success>=0 charset="" unicod</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>0 charset="" unicode</try>
  <literal>
    <try>0 charset="" unicode</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> charset="" unicode=</success>
  <attributes>[[0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>charset="" unicode=1</try>
  <success>="" unicode=1 stretc</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>"" unicode=1 stretch</try>
  <literal>
    <try>"" unicode=1 stretch</try>
    <success> unicode=1 stretchH=</success>
    <attributes>[]</attributes>
  </literal>
  <success> unicode=1 stretchH=</success>
  <attributes>[[", "]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>unicode=1 stretchH=1</try>
  <success>=1 stretchH=100 smoo</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>1 stretchH=100 smoot</try>
  <literal>
    <try>1 stretchH=100 smoot</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> stretchH=100 smooth</success>
  <attributes>[[1]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>stretchH=100 smooth=</try>
  <success>=100 smooth=1 aa=1 p</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>100 smooth=1 aa=1 pa</try>
  <literal>
    <try>100 smooth=1 aa=1 pa</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> smooth=1 aa=1 paddi</success>
  <attributes>[[1, 0, 0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>smooth=1 aa=1 paddin</try>
  <success>=1 aa=1 padding=0,0,</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0</try>
  <literal>
    <try>1 aa=1 padding=0,0,0</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> aa=1 padding=0,0,0,</success>
  <attributes>[[1]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>aa=1 padding=0,0,0,0</try>
  <success>=1 padding=0,0,0,0 s</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>1 padding=0,0,0,0 sp</try>
  <literal>
    <try>1 padding=0,0,0,0 sp</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> padding=0,0,0,0 spa</success>
  <attributes>[[1]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>padding=0,0,0,0 spac</try>
  <success>=0,0,0,0 spacing=1,1</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>0,0,0,0 spacing=1,1 </try>
  <literal>
    <try>0,0,0,0 spacing=1,1 </try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> spacing=1,1 outline</success>
  <attributes>[[0, ,, 0, ,, 0, ,, 0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>spacing=1,1 outline=</try>
  <success>=1,1 outline=0\ncommo</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>1,1 outline=0\ncommon</try>
  <literal>
    <try>1,1 outline=0\ncommon</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> outline=0\ncommon li</success>
  <attributes>[[1, ,, 1]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>outline=0\ncommon lin</try>
  <success>=0\ncommon lineHeight</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>0\ncommon lineHeight=</try>
  <literal>
    <try>0\ncommon lineHeight=</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success>\ncommon lineHeight=3</success>
  <attributes>[[0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>\ncommon lineHeight=3</try>
  <fail/>
</word>
<word>
  <try>common lineHeight=32</try>
  <success> lineHeight=32 base=</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<word>
  <try>lineHeight=32 base=2</try>
  <success>=32 base=26 scaleW=2</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>32 base=26 scaleW=25</try>
  <literal>
    <try>32 base=26 scaleW=25</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> base=26 scaleW=256 </success>
  <attributes>[[3, 2]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>base=26 scaleW=256 s</try>
  <success>=26 scaleW=256 scale</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>26 scaleW=256 scaleH</try>
  <literal>
    <try>26 scaleW=256 scaleH</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> scaleW=256 scaleH=2</success>
  <attributes>[[2, 6]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>scaleW=256 scaleH=25</try>
  <success>=256 scaleH=256 page</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>256 scaleH=256 pages</try>
  <literal>
    <try>256 scaleH=256 pages</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> scaleH=256 pages=0 </success>
  <attributes>[[2, 5, 6]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>scaleH=256 pages=0 p</try>
  <success>=256 pages=0 packed=</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>256 pages=0 packed=0</try>
  <literal>
    <try>256 pages=0 packed=0</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> pages=0 packed=0 al</success>
  <attributes>[[2, 5, 6]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>pages=0 packed=0 alp</try>
  <success>=0 packed=0 alphaChn</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>0 packed=0 alphaChnl</try>
  <literal>
    <try>0 packed=0 alphaChnl</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> packed=0 alphaChnl=</success>
  <attributes>[[0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>packed=0 alphaChnl=1</try>
  <success>=0 alphaChnl=1 redCh</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>0 alphaChnl=1 redChn</try>
  <literal>
    <try>0 alphaChnl=1 redChn</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> alphaChnl=1 redChnl</success>
  <attributes>[[0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>alphaChnl=1 redChnl=</try>
  <success>=1 redChnl=0 greenCh</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>1 redChnl=0 greenChn</try>
  <literal>
    <try>1 redChnl=0 greenChn</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> redChnl=0 greenChnl</success>
  <attributes>[[1]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>redChnl=0 greenChnl=</try>
  <success>=0 greenChnl=0 blueC</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>0 greenChnl=0 blueCh</try>
  <literal>
    <try>0 greenChnl=0 blueCh</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> greenChnl=0 blueChn</success>
  <attributes>[[0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>greenChnl=0 blueChnl</try>
  <success>=0 blueChnl=0\nchars </success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>0 blueChnl=0\nchars c</try>
  <literal>
    <try>0 blueChnl=0\nchars c</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success> blueChnl=0\nchars co</success>
  <attributes>[[0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>blueChnl=0\nchars cou</try>
  <success>=0\nchars count=0\n</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>0\nchars count=0\n</try>
  <literal>
    <try>0\nchars count=0\n</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success>\nchars count=0\n</success>
  <attributes>[[0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>\nchars count=0\n</try>
  <fail/>
</word>
<word>
  <try>chars count=0\n</try>
  <success> count=0\n</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<word>
  <try>count=0\n</try>
  <success>=0\n</success>
  <attributes>[]</attributes>
</word>
<value>
  <try>0\n</try>
  <literal>
    <try>0\n</try>
    <fail/>
  </literal>
  <success>\n</success>
  <attributes>[[0]]</attributes>
</value>
<word>
  <try>\n</try>
  <fail/>
</word>
<word>
  <try></try>
  <fail/>
</word>
```